# Is Jaxb2Marshaller compatible with Spring boot 3+ and Jaxb 4?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jaxb, marshalling, spring-ws

I am upgrading my project from spring boot 2.7 -> spring boot 3.1. Still using SOAP in this project, so we are dependant on Jaxb & spring WS.

I am generating Java classes with `com.helger.maven:jaxb40-maven-plugin` from xsd files & using `org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime` inherited from `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent` for unmarshalling to the generated Java classes.

My question is, what Marshaller should I use in a service that's extending `WebServiceGatewaySupport`? Right now I am using `Jaxb2Marshaller`, but I am unsure whether it's right, since the [the spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/oxm/jaxb/Jaxb2Marshaller.html) is saying:

> Implementation of the GenericMarshaller interface for JAXB 2.2.

Would appreciate some advice here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It will use/delegate to JAXB that is available. So if it uses the JAXB version that utilizes Jakarta packages it should work.

Comment: @M.Deinum okay, so it should work even if I am using jaxb 4? Just confused that the docs is saying it's an interface for JAXB 2.2. On the other hand, there is no other JAXB marshaller in the latest version of spring oxm.